# Elasticsearch Data too large

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I can't see the data in the dashboard. It always appears No results found, but there is data with te filters applied. I have seen in the Response tab and I get

```
"reason":"ElasticsearchException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [@timestamp] would be larger than limit of [623326003/594.4mb]];
```

How could I change this limit for being able to visualize all the visualizations in the dashboard?

I have used "cat /proc/meminfo" to see how is my RAM, and I have

```
MemTotal:        8059268 kB
MemFree:          141872 kB
Buffers:          183700 kB
Cached:          5532044 kB
SwapCached:          460 kB
Active:          2624192 kB
Inactive:        4740612 kB
Active(anon):     793784 kB
Inactive(anon):   855316 kB
Active(file):    1830408 kB
Inactive(file):  3885296 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1572860 kB
SwapFree:        1569772 kB
Dirty:              5296 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1648660 kB
Mapped:           586712 kB
Shmem:                40 kB
Slab:             462420 kB
SReclaimable:     398560 kB
SUnreclaim:        63860 kB
KernelStack:        4944 kB
PageTables:        12192 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     5602492 kB
Committed_AS:    2018216 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       29564 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359701040 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   1499136 kB
```

I think that I have too much in the cache. 
I have left the default parameters for ES_MIN_MEM , ES_MAX_MEM and ES_HEAP_SIZE..
Now my question is... I should change the ES_HEAP_SIZE to the 50% of the total RAM memory? (4 GB) or only 50% of the free memory? (141872 kB /2 = 70MB aprox)

Comment: check the out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239625/significant-terms-causes-a-circuitbreakingexception. It may solve your problem.

Comment: Also take a look to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html#circuit-breaker

Comment: Here is another answer that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266361/elasticsearch-aggregation-broken-after-upgrade-to-1-7-3/33266637#33266637